# ASP.NET MVC 3 EF Code First - Master Details CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 EF Code First with Razor + SQLserver and Want to implement Master Details scenario (like Order, Orderlines) with CRUD operations. I have come across some online examples like http://hasibulhaque.com/index.php/2011/master-detail-crud-operations-ef-asp-net-mvc-3/ but they heavily depends on JQuery or other complex implementations. Can somebody suggest me some step by step approach with a clean code?

Answer (score 0):

there are good tutorials at the asp.net site.
and i recommend you switch to mvc4 learning.
here is a link:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: I just checked this tutorial, However it is not a real Master-Details CRUD (though appearance is similar). I can easily implement such filteration using MVC-3 but my concern is CRUD in Master-Details (Like an invoice:  Invoice Header & Invoice-Item details) Thanks anyway

Comment: not at all). i thought you want a good codefirst sample and then you could write something more complicated based on that example

Answer (score 0):

If you want scaffolding do it for you, unfortunately it's not possible and you **can't** do that **simply**. Besides, you **must** use jquery and ajax to implement what you want.

I think the best and simplest way for you is that you have a view for creating Form and at the bottom of it put a fieldset to assign FormFields to it.

For the fieldset, you should have two partial views: One for create and another for edit. The partial view for creating should be something like this:

```
@model myPrj.Models.Form_FormFieldInfo

@{ 
    var index = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
    string ln = (string)ViewBag.ListName;
    string hn = ln + ".Index";
}

<tr>
    <td>        
        <input type="hidden" name="@hn" value="@index" />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FormFieldID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList(ln + "[" + index + "].FormFieldID", 
            new SelectList(new myPrj.Models.DbContext().FormFields, "ID", "FieldName"))
    </td>        
    <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" 
            value="Remove" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

By calling this partial view in the create place view ajaxly, you can render some elements for each tag. Each line of elements contains a label, a DropDownList containing tags, and a remove button to simply remove the created elements.

In the create place view, you have a bare table which will contain those elements you create through the partial view:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Form and FormFields</legend>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FormFields)</label>
    <table id="tblFields"></table>                                        
    <input type="button" id="btnAddTag" value="Add new Field"/>
    <img id="imgSpinnerl" src="~/Images/indicator-blue.gif" style="display:none;" />
</fieldset>
```

and you have the following script to create a line of elements for each tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddField").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/GetFormFieldRow/FormFields",
            type: 'GET', dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#tblFields").append(jqXHR.responseText);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#tblFields").append(jqXHR.responseText);
            },
            beforeSend: function () { $("#imgSpinnerl").show(); },
            complete: function () { $("#imgSpinnerl").hide(); }
        });
    });
});
```

The action method GetFormFieldRow is like the following:

```
public PartialViewResult GetFormFieldRow(string id = "")
{            
    ViewBag.ListName = id;
    return PartialView("_FormFieldPartial");
}
```

and your done for the create... The whole solution for your question has many codes for views, partial views, controllers, ajax calls and model binding. I tried to just show you the way because I really can't to post all of them in this answer.

[Here](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) is the full info and how-to.

Hope that this answer be useful and lead the way for you.