# Want to add multiple textbox in mvc4 regor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two Model Class

```
public partial class EndUser
{
    public EndUser()
    {
        this.Mobiles = new List<Mobile>();
    }

       public virtual long Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string FullName { get; set; }

       [DataType(DataType.Password)]
       public virtual string UserPassword { get; set; }
       public virtual string Email { get; set; }
       public virtual IList<Mobile> Mobiles { get; set; }

    public partial class Mobile
    {
       public virtual long Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string Number { get; set; }
       public virtual EndUser EndUser { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller

```
    public ActionResult CreateClient()
    {
        return View("CreateClient");
    }
```

Scaffold Template Create My view

### CreateClient

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>EndUser</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

But I want to add my Client Mobile From this view. How can i create multiply(unknown) text field to add mobile numbers? If client have more then one mobile number he can add more textbox by clicking "Add More Number" button. I cant create textbox for mobile number field.

Please help me out. Im new in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as easy as you think...

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17898362/1814343) for a quick info. Check [this](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) for a complete how-to

Comment: I just want to add a textbox with a button. if user want to add another mobile number, he can by clicking button. Thanks.

Comment: @AtonuTonmoy - I understand you completely! However, showing textboxes is just the simpleset part of the solution. What about to binding those numbers to your model...?!!! What about the validation...??! After creating the EndUser, what about editing it and its mobile numbers...??? All of these parts should handle correctly and these parts make it a not-so-easy solution...

Comment: I am reading those article. I did editing and adding EndUser and its mobile numbers from different views. But I want to do it from same view as add and  same view as edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can resume it in a few steps.

1. Create a view (ie) "DynamicMobileForm" where you will have a foreach Model.Mobiles, it should create a textbox for each item.
2. In the controller, create a Get method to retrieve only this partial DynamicMobileForm view (You can use the same model, should contain at least your Mobiles property loaded)
3. In your ABM form, remove any html regarding mobile, and paste this: 
   `@{Html.RenderPartial("DynamicMobileForm", Model);}` this will render this section only.
4. Now you just need a way to dynamically increment the amount of editors, this is very easy, create a button, and with jquery perform a call to controller with a POST Method, like DynamicMobileFormAddRow... Inside this method, you only need to Add() a new instance inside your Model.Mobiles list, and return the same model as your GetMethod.

When the page loads, will render your partial section only, adding a new textbox, and when you submit it, will automatically post it inside your Mobiles Array.

Hope it helps.